# Flutter: keep old value until implicit animation is done

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-container, flutter-opacity

I have this code:

```
AnimatedOpacity(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  opacity: _text == 'hide text'? 0 : 1,
  child: Text(_text),
)
```

What is the easiest way to show old value of text (eg not 'hide text', but whatever is there before the text changes to this) for the duration of fading the text out?

Comment: check `onEnd` callback

Comment: But the text is changed onBegin, that is the problem, not onEnd.. I know there are many solutions, I'm just looking for a one liner or something veery simple:)

Comment: sorry, so I don't know what you want to achieve actually...

Comment: I think you know and you're right, I will just create a callback, that's probably the easiest.. Just wanted to avoid passing a function to this widget and tought there may be some out of the box (even more then onEnd) solutions for such cases..

Comment: But yes, my question was I don't want to change the state of text after one second, if it changes first..

Comment: just create your own widget as wrapper and reuse it, the current implicit animation widgets don't support what you want

Comment: How can I do that? :)

Comment: can you give us more details about what you want to do? If you want to see the old value, you will never see the new value because the opacity will be 0.

Comment: It's really simple, I just can't think of any simple solution currently. So when the text is 'hide text' I want to fade the widget out (in 1 second). But the problem is, first the text changes, then the fading out happens. I just don't want to display 'hide text' for one second before it fades out. The text is actually a counter that I don't want to show when the value = zero.. When the counter changes from zero to positive number, I again want to show the text - but in this case, it already works, since the text changes before the animation starts.

Comment: I could also just save previous value and set the text like this:  text =='hide text'? previousText : currentText.. But I'm looking for a better solution and this for some reason glitches..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own Widget to do what you need.
I created a sample for you:

**Result**

[image]

**Explanation**

First, I created this code, where the main value is "show text", when the user press the button, the value will be updated to "hide text" and the animation will start.

There is a function `fadeBuilder` that you can use to validate when you want to hide the text, in this sample the condition to hide the text is `value == 'hide text'`

```dart
class _SampleViewState extends State<SampleView> {
  String _myText = 'show text';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        MyAnimatedTextOpacity(
          value: _myText,
          fadeBuilder: (value) => value == 'hide text',
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _myText = 'hide text';
            });
          },
          child: const Text('change text'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Now this is the custom widget:

```dart
typedef FadeBuilder = bool Function(String value);

class MyAnimatedTextOpacity extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAnimatedTextOpacity({
    required this.value,
    required this.fadeBuilder,
    super.key,
  });

  final String value;
  final FadeBuilder fadeBuilder;

  @override
  State<MyAnimatedTextOpacity> createState() => _MyAnimatedTextOpacityState();
}

class _MyAnimatedTextOpacityState extends State<MyAnimatedTextOpacity> {
  late final String _value = widget.value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedOpacity(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      opacity: widget.fadeBuilder(widget.value) ? 0 : 1,
      child: Text(_value),
    );
  }
}
```

A new sample based on your requirements:

Result

[image]

Code:

```dart
class BadgesDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const BadgesDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<BadgesDemo> createState() => _BadgesDemoState();
}

class _BadgesDemoState extends State<BadgesDemo> {
  int? badgeValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Badges Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: BadgeWidget(
          value: badgeValue?.toString(),
          child: const Icon(Icons.phone),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          // Assign the badge value
          setState(() {
            badgeValue = Random().nextInt(100);
          });
        },
        label: const Text('Generate random number'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BadgeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const BadgeWidget({
    required this.child,
    this.value,
    super.key,
  });

  final Widget child;
  final String? value;

  @override
  State<BadgeWidget> createState() => _BadgeWidgetState();
}

class _BadgeWidgetState extends State<BadgeWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant BadgeWidget oldWidget) {
    if (widget.value != oldWidget.value) {
      _controller.forward(from: 0);
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const dotSize = 20.0;
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.green[400],
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _controller.reverse();
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: widget.child,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        if (widget.value != null)
          Positioned(
            right: -dotSize / 3,
            top: -dotSize / 3,
            child: FadeTransition(
              opacity: _controller,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                width: dotSize,
                height: dotSize,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.value!,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such kind answer! It is still not exactly what I want:) this always shows the previous value, and this fix my problem but brings another one. When the counter changes from 0 to 1 (or other positive number), I need to show new value, not the old one. I only need to show the old value if the counter goes from positive number to 0. So this also works in just one way.

Comment: if you can attach a gif or the animation that you want, I could replicate that :)

Comment: Wow thanks, I will try to find it, but it's really a simple problrm, I'm just bad at explaining.
1. I need to fade OUT a text if the value goes from a positive number to zero. 
In this case, the OLD value must be shown for the duration of animation. 
2. I need to fade IN the text if a value goes from zero to positive number. 
In this case, the NEW value must be shown for the duration of animation. 

So never is zero shown.. + only animate if it changes to/from zero (not for other value changes)

Comment: Did you consider using explicit animations for this?

Comment: Yes, I probably should use that, right? I was just thinking it's such an easy case, it maybe has an equally easy solution, since flutter has so many out of the box tricks.. But yes, I can't think of any for this:)

Comment: I need a gif/video to see what you need exactly :D

Comment: I can't find any, but if it would behave like this badges usually do (fade in if you get a message, fade out of you click on it), it would be great: https://www.alamy.com/iphone-phone-and-messages-icons-showing-missed-calls-notification-badge-badges-usa-image215542418.html?imageid=8B2EA8C7-72E2-4A8C-8F4A-BB90C66D26B6&p=67200&pn=1&searchId=706a32ce36e55368f3ac15351fa5513c&searchtype=0

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately t it still doesn't work:) the whole problem is that when you call _controller.reverse, the number must also update to Zero. So the 0 still shows during the animation..

Comment: Well you have the idea, you can tweak that :) because i don't understand the issue

Comment: Yes, I tweaked it in the end and it worked:) thank you so much for your generous help!